# How can I update one column value in an RDD[Row]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I use scala for spark, I want to update one column value in an RDD, my data format is like this:

```
[510116,8042,1,8298,20170907181326,1,3,lineno805]
[510116,8042,1,8152,20170907182101,1,3,lineno805]
[510116,8042,1,8154,20170907164311,1,3,lineno805]
[510116,8042,1,8069,20170907165031,1,3,lineno805]
[510116,8042,1,8061,20170907170254,1,3,lineno805]
[510116,8042,1,9906,20170907171417,1,3,lineno805]
[510116,8042,1,8295,20170907174734,1,3,lineno805]
```

my scala code is like this:

```
 val getSerialRdd: RDD[Row]=……
```

I want to update the column which is contain data `20170907181326`, I wish the data like follow format:

```
[510116,8042,1,8298,2017090718,1,3,lineno805]
[510116,8042,1,8152,2017090718,1,3,lineno805]
[510116,8042,1,8154,2017090716,1,3,lineno805]
[510116,8042,1,8069,2017090716,1,3,lineno805]
[510116,8042,1,8061,2017090717,1,3,lineno805]
[510116,8042,1,9906,2017090717,1,3,lineno805]
[510116,8042,1,8295,2017090717,1,3,lineno805]
```

and output the RDD type like RDD[Row].

How I can do this?

Comment: 1) You have RDD[Row] already, why not a data frame then (optional question)? 2) What is the schema of the Row or data type of the column you want to update? Can you post `rdd.take(1)(0).schema`?

Comment: Yes, I have  RDD[Row] already, the data column contains 20170907181326 is String , it is  time column, I want to get 2017090718 from  20170907181326 column.

Comment: Any chance you can work with a data frame or you have to work with RDD? And also are all the strings in the column of the same length.

Comment: All the strings of the same lenght. For this getSerialRdd: RDD[Row],I had tranform and action some times, so   getSerialRdd: RDD[Row] is transform result. I only want transform one column value in RDD[row],then get the new RDD[row].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define an `update` method like this to update a field in the Row:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

def update(r: Row): Row = {
    val s = r.toSeq
    Row.fromSeq((s.take(4) :+ s(4).asInstanceOf[String].take(10)) ++ s.drop(5))
}

rdd.map(update(_)).collect

//res13: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = 
//       Array([510116,8042,1,8298,2017090718,1,3,lineno805], 
//             [510116,8042,1,8152,2017090718,1,3,lineno805], 
//             [510116,8042,1,8154,2017090716,1,3,lineno805], 
//             [510116,8042,1,8069,2017090716,1,3,lineno805], 
//             [510116,8042,1,8061,2017090717,1,3,lineno805], 
//             [510116,8042,1,9906,2017090717,1,3,lineno805], 
//             [510116,8042,1,8295,2017090717,1,3,lineno805])
```

---

A simpler approach would be to use DataFrame API and the `substring` function:

1) Create a data frame from the rdd:

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, rdd.take(1)(0).schema)
// df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_c0: string, _c1: string ... 6 more fields]
```

2) use `substring` to transform the column:

```
df.withColumn("_c4", substring($"_c4", 0, 10)).show
+------+----+---+----+----------+---+---+---------+
|   _c0| _c1|_c2| _c3|       _c4|_c5|_c6|      _c7|
+------+----+---+----+----------+---+---+---------+
|510116|8042|  1|8298|2017090718|  1|  3|lineno805|
|510116|8042|  1|8152|2017090718|  1|  3|lineno805|
|510116|8042|  1|8154|2017090716|  1|  3|lineno805|
|510116|8042|  1|8069|2017090716|  1|  3|lineno805|
|510116|8042|  1|8061|2017090717|  1|  3|lineno805|
|510116|8042|  1|9906|2017090717|  1|  3|lineno805|
|510116|8042|  1|8295|2017090717|  1|  3|lineno805|
+------+----+---+----+----------+---+---+---------+
```

3) convert data frame to rdd is easy:

```
val getSerialRdd = df.withColumn("_c4", substring($"_c4", 0, 10)).rdd
```

Comment: Thanks,Psidom. I use  the first method  for my programm, it is OK. I am a newer for spark learning. I feel so much things to learn.

Answer (score 3):

In some cases you might want to update a row with a schema

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema

def update(r: Row, i: Int, a: Any): Row = {

    val s: Array[Any] = r
      .toSeq
      .toArray
      .updated(i, a)

    new GenericRowWithSchema(s, r.schema)
}

rdd.map(update(_)).show(false)
```